# Unable to target nth child of styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I'm trying to target 3 children `div`s of a styled component, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with my syntax, and the styled component docs don't seem to cover this well. My code is:

```
const HamburgerButton = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 60%;
    min-width: 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    &:nth-child(1){
        width: 32px;
        min-height: 3px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    &:nth-child(2){
        width: 32px;
        min-height: 3px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    &:nth-child(3){
        width: 32px;
        min-height: 3px;
        background-color: red;
    }
`

const MobileNav = () => {

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
        <MobileNavContainer>
            <Name>
                <h1>Josh Bangle</h1>
            </Name>
            <HamburgerButton>
                <span />
                <span />
                <span />
            </HamburgerButton>
        </MobileNavContainer>
    );
}
```

the `nth-child(2)` selector seems to style the `HamburgerButton` component itself for some reason, so I can only imagine it's a syntax issue, although googling has done nothing to help me out with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

nth-child styles the element based on it's position *within the group* (this has confused me a million times over the years). `HamburgerButton` being the 2nd element within `MobleNavContainer`, it got styled. You want to add that class to the spans.

Comment: Ahhhh, so it doesn't target the specific child of the element you are applying the nth-child selector to, but rather the nth-child of the highest level parent? How about the > * selector? I used that instead and it styled all 3 of the spans properly, was that just good luck? lol

Comment: @JoshBangle  `>` targets direct descendents, so combined with the wild card, you targeted all elements that are children of the button. You _could_ use that with nth-child, but I think it's cleaner to apply the styles directly to the spans. It's easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const HamburgerButton = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 60%;
    min-width: 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    & span:nth-child(1){
        width: 32px;
        min-height: 3px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    & span:nth-child(2){
        width: 32px;
        min-height: 3px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    & span:nth-child(3){
        width: 32px;
        min-height: 3px;
        background-color: red;
    }
`
```

Putting a space between the & and the : tells the code to look out for child components. with the way you've written it above it is telling the code to look for the nth HamburgerButton. you can also write the code I have above without the span if you want to reference any nth child element

```js
& :nth-child(2){
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
margin-right: 1rem;
:nth-child(*what ever number*) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

to target every other child you can also replace *what ever number* with odd or even